# Async-await fetch call triggers duplicate alerts

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I've created an editor with JS and PHP to allow text and image changes on a webpage.
Consider the following JS function:

```
const publish = () => {

    if (unpublished || Object.keys(files).length) {

        // start spinning loader
        let icon = document.getElementById("loader");
        icon.innerText = 'refresh';
        icon.classList.add("spin");

        // text changes
        if (unpublished) {
            let parcel = new FormData();
            parcel.append("lang", langId);
            parcel.append("page", pageId);
            parcel.append("edits", JSON.stringify(edits));

            send(parcel);

            unpublished = false;
        }

        // image changes
        if (Object.keys(files).length) {

            Object.keys(files).forEach(section => {
                const length = Object.keys(files[section]).length;
                for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                    const tag = Object.keys(files[section])[i];
                    const file = Object.values(files[section])[i];
                    let parcel = new FormData();
                    parcel.append("lang", langId);
                    parcel.append("page", pageId);
                    parcel.append("section", section);
                    parcel.append(tag, file);

                    send(parcel);
                }
            })
            files = {};
        }

        async function send(parcel) {
            const response = await fetch("", {
                method: "POST",
                body: parcel,
            });
            if (!response.ok) alert(Error(response.statusText));
            if (!unpublished && !Object.keys(files).length) {

                // stop spinning loader
                icon.classList.remove("spin");
                icon.innerText = 'save';
                alert("changes published");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The changes (parcel) are processed with PHP. Everything works fine if the user changes either text or an image. However, if both are changed, the 'changes published' alert is triggered twice, even though the condition

> if (!unpublished && !Object.keys(files).length)

shouldn't be true until after

> files = {};

Comment: But you set `files = {};` *immediately* after the loop which fires off the asynchronous fetch requests - never `await`ing the `send()` calls. Don't use `!Object.keys(files).length` as an indicator for anything, use `Promise.all`.

Comment: @Bergi I tried, but remain unsure how to write this function using Promise.all and satisfy all 3 scenarios:

1. only text changes
2. only image changes
3. changes to both

Comment: Just `push` the promises that the `send()` calls return in an array. The changed text might send a parcel, the file uploads may send any number of parcels. After all are sent, you have an array of promises to wait for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Bergi Thanks, it's working now. Below is the result in case anyone needs it:

```
const publish = () => {

if (Object.keys(edits).length || Object.keys(files).length) {

    let promises = [];

    // start spinning loader
    let icon = document.getElementById("loader");
    icon.innerText = 'refresh';
    icon.classList.add("spin");

    // text changes
    if (Object.keys(edits).length) {
        let parcel = new FormData();
        parcel.append("lang", langId);
        parcel.append("page", pageId);
        parcel.append("edits", JSON.stringify(edits));

        promises.push(send(parcel));

        edits = {};
    }

    // image changes
    if (Object.keys(files).length) {

        Object.keys(files).forEach(section => {
            const length = Object.keys(files[section]).length;
            for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                const tag = Object.keys(files[section])[i];
                const file = Object.values(files[section])[i];
                let parcel = new FormData();
                parcel.append("lang", langId);
                parcel.append("page", pageId);
                parcel.append("section", section);
                parcel.append(tag, file);

                promises.push(send(parcel));
            }
        })

        files = {};
    }

    // send parcel
    async function send(parcel) {
        const response = await fetch("", {
            method: "POST",
            body: parcel,
        });
        if (!response.ok) alert(Error(response.statusText));
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {

        // stop spinning loader
        icon.classList.remove("spin");
        icon.innerText = 'save';
        alert("changes published");
        return;
    })
}
```

}